# Searching for more than one user

Tags: facebook, search

I would like to use Graph API to search for users whose names are "John" or "Mark".

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=john&type=user

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user

Is it possible to receive those informations using only one request? Something like "q1=mark&q2=john" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the batch API to group both requests in a single API call.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/